# How to automate the installation of .net framework 3.5 with terraform and powershell?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, .net, terraform

The operating system is Windows Server 2012.

[image]

This dialog box pops when a process starts on the server.

Is it possible to automate the installation of the feature?

Comment: The answer to your question is in the dialog: `or use the Server Manager cmdlets`. It should be possible to execute those via Terraform `remote-exec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command inside Powershell to install .Net Framework 3.5

```
Install-WindowsFeature Net-Framework-Core -source \\network\share\sxs
```